# Can you make assignments between PyTorch tensors using ragged indices without a for loop?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have two PyTorch `Tensor` objects of equal shape:

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn(2, 10)
y = torch.randn(2, 10)
```

Now, I have a list of indices (of the same length as the first `Tensor` axis) which give different starting positions in the second `Tensor` axis from which I want to assign values from `y` into `x`, i.e.,

```py
idxs = [2, 6]
for i, idx in enumerate(idxs):
    x[i, idx:] = y[i, idx:]
```

As above, I can do this with a for loop, but my question is whether there is a more efficient way of doing this without an explicit for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a index tensor on the second dimension of your tensor with

```py
second_dim_indices = torch.arange(x.shape[1])
```

and turn `idxs` into a tensor:

```py
idxs = torch.LongTensor(idxs)
```

Then, it is possible to compute a mask that's true when tensor index must be modified with :

```py
mask = second_dim_indices.unsqueeze(0) >= idxs.unsqueeze(1)
# in your case =
#  tensor([[False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,   True],
#          [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Note that we must unsqueeze indices and idxs to broadcast the `>=` operation.

Finally, use the mask to update `x`:

```py
x = y * mask + x * ~mask
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Doing some timing (for two 10x1000 Tensors) and your method seems to give an ~5 times speed improvement on a CPU and ~250 times speed improvement on a GPU!

Comment: Just to note, multiplying by the mask (as in this answer) seems significantly quicker than using the mask for index assignment, e.g., doing an equivalent, `x[mask.expand(x.shape[0], -1)] = y[mask.expand(x.shape[0], -1)]`, while still faster than the explicit for loop, is slower than the multiplication.

Comment: Maybe using in-place operation could speed up even more. Instead of `x = y * mask + x * ~mask` you can try `x *= ~mask` followed by `x += y * mask`.

Comment: Yes, that does give a bit more of a speed up - the increase is by about 16% in the same case as my first comment.

Comment: However, in my real-world usage case, doing things in-place seems to show no appreciable difference.